# Qt: Proper Method to Implement Panning(Drag)

Tags: c++, qt

QGraphicsview has a method `setDragMode(ScrollHandDrag)` to enable panning with the left mouse click. But I wanted to enable panning when the mouse wheel is clicked(the middle button) and created the following custom implementation to pan:

```
//Within a custom derived class of QGraphicsView
//pan is true when wheel is clicked and false when released
//last Pos is defined somewhere else in the class

void GridView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
     if(pan){
         QPointF currentPos = event->pos();
         QPointF relPos = currentPos - lastPos;
         lastPos = currentPos;

         //this is what creates the panning effect
         translate(relPos.x(), relPos.y());
     }
     QGraphicsView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

This works fine for the most part. But for example, if I scale the identity matrix by 1,000,000 this method fails and stops panning (as if the view got stuck). This problem doesn't arise when I use `setDragMode()`

What would be the proper custom implementation of `setDragMode()` so it is enabled by the wheel click?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works for me... it tricks Qt into thinking the user is pressing the left mouse button when he's really pressing the middle one.

```
void GridView :: mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent * e)
{
   if (e->button() == MidButton)
   {
      QMouseEvent fake(e->type(), e->pos(), LeftButton, LeftButton, e->modifiers());
      QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(&fake);
   }
   else QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(e);
}

void GridView :: mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent * e)
{
   if (e->button() == MidButton)
   {
      QMouseEvent fake(e->type(), e->pos(), LeftButton, LeftButton, e->modifiers());
      QGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent(&fake);
   }
   else QGraphicsView::mouseReleaseEvent(e);
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent work around! I coupled it with calls to setInteractive true/false and setDragMode ScrollHandDrag/NoDrag for press and release events respectively

Comment: @Shootfast Great stuff. Did the same.

Comment: This may not work as intended if you need LeftButton event for something else. An alternative approach is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5156978/2055281

Comment: I think it will work as intended, since it doesn't change the GridView's responses to genuine left-button events in any way (left-button events simply fail the if e->button()==MidButton test and therefore the code calls up to the superclass the same as always)