# qt chart move view with pressed middle mouse button

Tags: c++, qt, qtcharts

I'm currently working with Qts Chart plotting tool. I have now a plot where I can zoom in and out by using the chartview class provieded by [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-zoomlinechart-example.html) example (with small adjustments).
I would like to see the ability to not only zoom, but also move my view a pressed middle mouse button (which is used a lot in other applications and therefore is very intuitive).

How can I do this in Qt? How can I check if a middle mouse button is pressed and released and change my view at the plot if the mouse moves during a pressed middle mouse button...

I'm sure someone has coded this before and would really appreciate a small example/help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551466/qt-proper-method-to-implement-panningdrag/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt: Proper Method to Implement Panning(Drag)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551466/qt-proper-method-to-implement-panningdrag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to derive a class from `QChartView` and overload the mouse events:

```
class ChartView: public QChartView
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    ChartView(Chart* chart, QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:

    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
    virtual void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;

private:

    QPointF m_lastMousePos;
};

ChartView::ChartView(Chart* chart, QWidget *parent)
    : QChartView(chart, parent)
{
    setDragMode(QGraphicsView::NoDrag);
    this->setMouseTracking(true);
}

void ChartView::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->button() == Qt::MiddleButton)
    {
        QApplication::setOverrideCursor(QCursor(Qt::SizeAllCursor));
        m_lastMousePos = event->pos();
        event->accept();
    }

    QChartView::mousePressEvent(event);
}

void ChartView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    // pan the chart with a middle mouse drag
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::MiddleButton)
    {
        QRectF bounds = QRectF(0,0,0,0);
        for(auto series : this->chart()->series())
            bounds.united(series->bounds())

        auto dPos = this->chart()->mapToValue(event->pos()) - this->chart()->mapToValue(m_lastMousePos);

        if (this->rubberBand() == QChartView::RectangleRubberBand)
            this->chart()->zoom(bounds.translated(-dPos.x(), -dPos.y()));
        else if (this->rubberBand() == QChartView::HorizontalRubberBand)
            this->chart()->zoom(bounds.translated(-dPos.x(), 0));
        else if (this->rubberBand() == QChartView::VerticalRubberBand)
            this->chart()->zoom(bounds.translated(0, -dPos.y()));

        m_lastMousePos = event->pos();
        event->accept();
    }

    QChartView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: what is m_zoomRect?

Comment: this was part of a larger project (https://github.com/nholthaus/chart) which also extended chart and handled zooming. I've edited the answer, but `m_zoomRect` in this case is the union of all the charts series boundaries.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to offer a simpler version of Nicolas's `mouseMoveEvent()`:

```
    void ChartView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
        // pan the chart with a middle mouse drag
        if (event->buttons() & Qt::MiddleButton)
        {
            auto dPos = event->pos() - lastMousePos_;
            chart()->scroll(-dPos.x(), dPos.y());

            lastMousePos_ = event->pos();
            event->accept();

            QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor();
        }

        QChartView::mouseMoveEvent(event);
    }
```

Also, be sure to include `QApplication::restoreOverrideCursor()` so the cursor returns to usual after the move is done.

Comment: You will need to initialize `lastMousePos_` first.