# Move QGraphicsItem only when pressing inside the shape. Otherwise, drag scene

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsscene, custom-widgets

I have a `QGraphicsView` with a bigger `QGraphicsScene` that can be dragged.
In the `QGraphicsScene` I have a subclassed `QGraphicsItem` (`TestItem`) that displays a `QGraphicsPixmapItem`, which can have random shapes.
(I don't use `QGraphicsPixmapItem` directly because of extra functionality to be implemented in the future)

I want this item to be movable, but only if the user presses within the shape of the item. If outside the shape, but still inside the `boundingRectangle`, I want the scene behind it to be dragged. This because the `boundingRectangle` can be much bigger than the shape and the user doesn't see it, so it would be weird trying to drag the scene near the `Pixmap` and it not working.

This is my subclassed item:

```
TestItem::TestItem(QPointF position, QPixmap testImage, double width, 
                    double length, QGraphicsItem * parent):
    QGraphicsItem(parent),
    m_boundingRect(QRectF(0,0,5, 5)),
    m_dragValid(false),
    m_path(QPainterPath()),
    mp_image(new QGraphicsPixmapItem(this))
{
    setBoundingRect(QRectF(0,0,width,length));
    setPos(position - boundingRect().center());
    setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
    mp_image->setPixmap(testImage.scaled(width, length));
    m_path = mp_image->shape();
}

QPainterPath TestItem::shape()
{
    return m_path;
} 

QRectF TestItem::boundingRect() const
{
    return m_boundingRect;
}

void TestItem::setBoundingRect(QRectF newRect)
{
    prepareGeometryChange();
    m_boundingRect = newRect;
}
```

I've tried overriding the mouse events like this, but all it brings me is no functionality at all when outside the shape but inside the bounding rectangle

```
void TestItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(shape().contains(event->pos()))
    { 
        QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(event);
        m_dragValid = true;
    }
}

void TestItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(m_dragValid)
        QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(event);
} 

void TestItem::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(m_dragValid)
        QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent(event);

    m_dragValid = false;
}
```

which of course makes sense, but I wouldn't know how to implement the dragging of the scene, since it's the scene itself that sends the mouse events to the graphics item.

(My `QGraphicsView` is setup to `DragMode` `QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag`)

Anyone have ideas?

Comment: See related discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753681/how-to-pan-images-in-qgraphicsview

Comment: Yes, thank you @Archie. That discussion had exactly what I was looking for. I just needed to add a `event->ignore();` to my mouse events. I'll write a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. I only needed to add a `event->ignore();` to my mouse events.

```
void TestItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
   if(shape().contains(event->pos()))
    {  
        QGraphicsItem::mousePressEvent(event);
        m_dragValid = true;
    }
    else
        event->ignore();
}

void TestItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(m_dragValid)
         QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(event);
    else
        event->ignore();
} 

void TestItem::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(m_dragValid)
        QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
    else
        event->ignore();

    m_dragValid = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to enable `QGraphicsItem::ItemClipsToShape` flag:

> The item clips to its own shape. The item cannot draw or receive mouse, tablet, drag and drop or hover events outside its shape. It is disabled by default.

Comment: I have done this, and nothing changes. I also tried `QGraphicsItem::ItemClipsChildrenToShape` with no success. The item moves if pressed inside the bounding rectangle